# How to restore layout position after expanding and collapsing TextView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, cardview

I have a CardView and below a TextView. When you click the CardView
it toggles the visibility of the TextView and it works fine but
when it expands it pushes the next item in my LinearLayout and when it collapses again there just a void where the TextView lied.

How do I make it so that when the TextView collapse(visibility GONE),
the next item in the layout also goes up where it was the first time?

```
//it starts hidden 
textView3.visibility = View.GONE

cardView.setOnClickListener{
        textView3.toggleVisibility()

    }

 fun View.toggleVisibility() {
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    } else {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `toggleVisibility` to

```
if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
    visibility = View.GONE
} else {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

When you set the visibility to `invisible`, the layout constraints remain but the view is hidden. Setting it to `gone` will also remove the layout constraints.